# List items to wrap in div

Tags: html, css

looking for some code to wrap a li items in a div with a set height.
When list items dont fit the height it will spill over to the right. 
also looking to align them to the left of that div with bullet point still visible.

would also be nice if you would be able to control the "space" in between so it doesn't look squished.

I wrote the code how i would like it displayed knowing it wont. hopefully it helps to explain what i am after.

```html
<div>

<ul>
<li> 1</li>   (space)   <li> 4</li>   (space)   <li> 7</li>
<li> 2</li>   (space)   <li> 5</li>   (space)   <li> 8</li>
<li> 3</li>   (space)   <li> 6</li>   (space)   <li> 9</li>



</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `column-count` for this. Check snippet below..
for detail you can take reference from https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> 1</li>
  <li> 2</li>
  <li> 3</li>
  <li> 4</li>
  <li> 5</li>
  <li> 6</li>
  <li> 7</li>
  <li> 8</li>
  <li> 9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: PERFECT THANK YOU........... just one more thing i see the columns arent centered in the div any way of doing this. seems to be sitting more left..